# Clang fails to find stdio.h. Which flag should I add?

Tags: c++, macos, header, clang, stdio

Here is a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this program with Clang gives the error below.

```
$ clang test.cpp
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

The program above is a shortened version from a large project. I can neither change the program, or change the compiler to use, namely clang. So it seems to me the only options  is to change  environment variables so to alter the flags used by Clang. Which flag should I use?

Comment: include <cstdio> when programming c++.

Comment: Thanks. But as mentioned in the question, the program is from a large project that I cannot modify.

Comment: Do you have to compile with clang?  If you're working on oxs you can use homebrew to install gcc and then compile with g++

Comment: Check your installation.  If the compiler can't find `<stdio.h>`, there is something up with the installation.  Have you installed the 'command line tools' if you're on Mac OS X?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How to check the installation? Do you mean Clang should have found stdio.h in a correct setting of Mac OS?

Comment: Most likely, you are missing the glibc (or equivalent) on your system. Although I would have thought that the package install system would tell you that it needs this too.

Comment: @hetepeperfan No. Clang should work well for CPP program in general.

Comment: If it is installed properly, `clang` finds the header without any special options.  Have you run `xcode-select --install`?  You may need to do that.  Or you may need to download and install the command line tools separately.  (On my Mac OS X 10.10.5 machine, your command line works fine on your program; I would be surprised if it didn't on my 10.11.2 machine — and would look to fix the installation of XCode.)

Comment: @zell: clang is the compiler. It needs a runtime library and header files, which would be a separate package. Do you have a /usr/include at all? Or /usr/local/include?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Sure./usr/include or /usr/local/include exist in the Mac OS. What do you mean?

Comment: And have stdio.h in it? What does `clang++ test.cpp -v` tell you about where it looks for include files?

Comment: @Mats Thanks. the '-v' does help me to diagnose the issue.  I am working on that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right. Actually, I need to install the xcode command line options.  Problem solved. Thanks so much.