# Clang fails to find iostream. What should I do?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, iostream

Earlier, I posed a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34254127/1566221).

I have the following program extracted from a large project in my Mac OS

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with Clang fails with the following error:

```
$ clang test.cpp
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

For information,

A) I have already installed xcode command line tools, using xcodeselect --install. But it seems iostream does not locate in the default search path of clang.

B) Using g++ instead of clang compiles the program. But in my problem, I am not allowed to use other compiler than clang, or to change the source program.

C) I can see workaround techniques, e.g, by  tweaking the search path in .bashrc or with some symbolic link, etc.  But I feel reluctant to use them, because it seems that I have an installation problem with my Clang and tweaking the path only helps to avoid one of these  path issues.

Comment: @Baum, 101010: Please take time to read through other people's questions.

Answer (score 2):

`clang` and `clang++` do different things. If you want to compile C++ code, you need to use `clang++`

Alternatively you can invoke c++ compiler directly by providing language name explicitely:

```
clang -x=c++
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with clang++, giving  the same error message. In addition, the program is a third-party project whose compiler is fixed and I am not allowed to switch to other compiler, as I mentioned in (B) of my question.

Comment: clang -x=c++  test.cpp gives "clang-3.7: error: language not recognized: '=c++' ". Is it normal?

Comment: @zell. Yes, it is normal. Lose the `=`; `-x c++`

Comment: Thanks but neither clang -x c++ test.cpp or clang -x=c++ test.cpp works.